# How to Resize Modal height and width in react-bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to use React Bootstrap Modal in my application but the dialog is too small, and I want to make it bigger. How can I achieve that ? I already finished the Code but i think the css doesn't work

Here's the code:

```
        <Modal show={showModal} onHide={handleClose} className='modalSize'>
            <Modal.Body >
                <Row>
                    <Col lg={6}>
                        <img 
                            className
                            src= {modalData.picture}
                        />
                    </Col>

                    <Col lg={6}>
                        <h1>{modalData.name}</h1>
                        <h1>{modalData.position}</h1>
                    </Col>
                </Row>

            </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
```

CSS :

```
.modalSize{
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the react-bootstrap docs: [Size](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#optional-sizes)

You can add a parameter for the size of the modal just using `size="lg"` as below

```
function Example() {
  const [smShow, setSmShow] = useState(false);
  const [lgShow, setLgShow] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={() => setSmShow(true)} className="me-2">
        Small modal
      </Button>
      <Button onClick={() => setLgShow(true)}>Large modal</Button>
      <Modal
        size="sm"
        show={smShow}
        onHide={() => setSmShow(false)}
        aria-labelledby="example-modal-sizes-title-sm"
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="example-modal-sizes-title-sm">
            Small Modal
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>...</Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
      <Modal
        size="lg"
        show={lgShow}
        onHide={() => setLgShow(false)}
        aria-labelledby="example-modal-sizes-title-lg"
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="example-modal-sizes-title-lg">
            Large Modal
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>...</Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I dont think the lg is enough for my needs

Comment: @KimSan, read further down the link for full screen, responsive and custom sizing.